# How to check if SharedPreferences exists or not

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm checking in this way if the file exists, but I need to go beyond, I need to know if there is one in specific, is there any way?

```
File f = new File("/data/data/com.eventrid.scanner/shared_prefs/Eventrid.xml");
          if (f.exists()){

          }
          else{

          }
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation? Isn't there a `contains` method?

Comment: method does not exist as a way, my idea is also not read the file, I just wanted to know if there is any easier way.

Comment: You want to extract information from a file without reading it?

Comment: I just want to know if there is a preference, I do not care value, I redirect to another layout if it exists,

Comment: This method of checking is still useful, if one needs to know if a preference file of the given name (Eventrid in this case) was ever created. I do have a valid use scenario, where this is important to know. Thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` has a `contains(String key)` method, which can be used to check if an entry with the given key exists.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 33):

Well, one could do:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("sp_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
    if(!sharedPrefs.contains("initialized")){
        ed = sharedPrefs.edit();

        //Indicate that the default shared prefs have been set
        ed.putBoolean("initialized", true);

        //Set some default shared pref
        ed.putString("myDefString", "wowsaBowsa");

        ed.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

If you know the exact number of preferences you have you can:

```
public void isPreferencesSet(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return (sharedPreferences.getAll().size() == exactNumberOfPreferences);
}
```

This works because the preferences file stored in /data/data/myApp/shared_prefs/myApp_prefrences.xml contains a preference's value pair only if its value has been set.

Answer (score 1):

**Check if SharedPreferences key exists:**

```
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(mPrefs.getAll().containsKey("KeyName")){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 fun checkLoginInfo(): Boolean{
    val saveLogin = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SAVE_LOGIN, false)
    return saveLogin
}

 Checks whether the preferences contains a preference. 
 @param(SAVE_LOGIN) key The name of the preference to check.
 @param(false) default
 @return Returns true if the preference exists in the preferences, otherwise false.
```